# Reference Request: Prognosis and Decision Trees in Random Survival Trees

Tags: survival, random-forest

I would like to know if there are any good references showing how using random forests in a survival analysis setting allows the building of a decision tree showing how observations were classified and how this is interpretable and helpful in prognosis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for the original R-newsletter articles which introduce the Random Forests package for survival.  The R-Project has some strong packages that a lot of students use.